# "No matching profiles found" with SiriKit in Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, provisioning-profile, visual-studio-mac, sirikit

I haven't found if anybody had similar problem. My Visual Studio for Mac project stopped seeing application provisioning profile after I added SiriKit support there. Just can't find it, nor automatically, neither when trying to set manually.

I have checked bundle id and all my Entitlements several times, as well as removing cache, relaunch Visual Studio and even restarting Mac, but nothing helped.

#### First point:

Xcode can see this provision profile perfectly. I've created test project with Extensions for Siri. It can see the provision profile, and even launch the test app on the real device. But not in Visual Studio for Mac.

#### Second point:

Visual Studio can see other provision profiles, which doesn't have SiriKit enabled. As well as the newly created provision profiles (without SiriKit).

Any ideas would be helpful.

#### My system set:

- macOS Mojave, Version 10.14.2
- Xcode, Version 10.1 (10B61)
- Visual Studio for Mac (Community), Version 7.7.1 (build 15)
- Mono Framework, Version 5.16.0.221
- Xamarin.iOS, Version 12.2.1.12

## Update

Looks like apple fixed it (see last comments in [this thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/343811#343811)). I was able to create new provision (with new bundle id) and VS for Mac saw it successfully. However I guess you need to regenerate old provisions at apple developer portal, as they still have duplicate keys.

Also, looks like an update for VS for Mac will come in the nearest few days, that will fix this issue with duplicate key (see [this](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/pull/5286) pull request),  so you can just wait)

Question is closed

Comment: I've had strange provisioning issues between Xcode and VS/Xamarin.  I've found manually downloading the profile and dragging/dropping onto the Xcode icon resolves them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug which is causing such issues. Already reported here..

https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/343811#343811

Comment: Yes,  the Xamarin iOS team is aware of it and is working on getting a fix out: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/5277